# Spock rightShift (mocking) operator apparently not working

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock

Here is my Spock unit test:

```
def "when favorite color is red then doSomething produces empty list of things"() {
    given:
    FizzBuzz fizzBuzz = Mock(FizzBuzz)
    fizzBuzz.name >> 'Dark Helmet'
    fizzBuzz.attributes >> [:]
    fizzBuzz.attributes["favcolor"] >> 'red'
    fizzBuzz.attributes["age"] >> '36'

    Something something = new Something(fizzBuzz)

    when:
    Whoah whoah = something.doSomething()

    then:
    !whoah.things
}
```

And here is the `FizzBuzz` mock:

```
public interface FizzBuzz extends Serializable {
    Map<String, Object> getAttributes();
}
```

When I run this I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method rightShift() on null object

at com.commercehub.houston.SomethingSpec.when favorite color is red then doSomething produces empty list of things fail(SomethingSpec.groovy:18)

Process finished with exit code 255
```

The 'null object' its referring to on Line 18 is either `fizzBuzz` or its `attributes` map. **Why?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're attempting to use multiple levels of indirection, and the `>>` is getting applied to the result of `.attributes["favcolor"]`, which is null (since `.attributes` is an empty map). Instead, just initialize the map:

```
fizzBuzz.attributes >> [favcolor: 'red', age: 36]
```

(Also, did you really mean `age` to be a string?)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I realized I was accidentally declaring the result of the `when` block.

```
when:
Whoah whoah = something.doSomething() >> expectedResult
```